# Javascript function fails to create new Object

Tags: javascript

Why would this code not work as expected? Is anything missing?

```
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

var j = User('Jack');
alert(j.name)
```

Comment: `new User('Jack');`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use `new` to create user, `this` means global object window.
`window.name` differs in different browsers.

So should be `new User("Jack");`

Comment: "window.name differs in different browsers" it won't differ anymore after you run this code :)

Comment: @ben336 LOL, yes it won't differ

Answer (score 2):

```
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

var j = new User('Jack');
alert(j.name)
```

You need a `new` keyword to use `User` as a constructor.  Without it, `this` in `User` refers to the global object (window in the browser), and no new object is created.  `j` will be undefined.

Using `new` creates a new object which is assigned to j, and the `this` is then bound to that object.  So `name` will be set on the newly created object, rather than the window.

Comment: I don't think that's enough. We're looking at a function here, not a class. Does `this` really refer to the function? I don't think so.

Comment: @Maxim You're not very big on JavaScripts prototype based inheritance, are you? :-)

Comment: @amn Guess not, not *that* big at least. :)

Comment: @MaximKumpan JS convention is that constructors are capitalized, he's assigning it to a variable despite no return statement and then expecting that variable to have a name property.  It is VERY clear he means it to be a constructor.

Comment: @ben336 Yes, quite. Except I have doubts about `this` returning the function call, rather than the *object* up the hierarchy (`window` in this case most likely). Capitalizing a function name does not turn it into an object.

Comment: @MaximKumpan what are you talking about?  `this` will refer to a new object when called with new.  Otherwise it will refer to the global object since it was called without being bound to an object.  Given his code it WILL be the global object.  Feel free to test it out.

Comment: @ben336 I'm talking about `this` being used in a function scope. He intends `this` to return the `User` function, not the global object, which it probably bleedin' will.

Comment: @MaximKumpan Capitalizing a function does not turn it into an object.  But there is a convention that constructors in JS are capitalized and other functions are not.  Constructors can then create objects when used with `new` (technically any function can be used that way, which is why there is a convention to distinguish constructors)

Comment: @MaximKumpan No he intends `this` to refer to the new object that he wants created and assigned to j (because thats what he references later).  Which is what happens if you add `new`.  Which is what I said in my answer.  Why would `this` point to the function?  Whats the point in that?

Comment: @ben336 Ah, now it all makes sense. Yes, you are correct. I did not know this particular bit about prototyping.